# common flutter engine for 2 android activities

Tags: android, flutter

I have 2 activities which inherit from FlutterActivity(). As I know when we are starting the activity flutterEngine is created. I would like to have common flutterEngine (1) for both activities. The question is how I should attaching/detaching engine and when? Also how should I pop activity and detach it from one activity and attach to other activity?

I would like to achieve effect like which activity is visible then this one flutter engine is attached.

Comment: hi did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunetelly nope